# How to configure webpack to "serve" existing dev site?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

I do not actually know what to google since I do not know the term or what do you call this process.

So basically, I have a dev site: `http://mylocalwebdev.test` which is written in CodeIgniter, and I am trying to create a page `http://mylocalwebdev.test/image-switcher-demo` which frontend will be developed using React. (this is basically my practice of React and webpack)

So, I have created my webpack config, and it can generate the `bundle.js`, and now I want to use `webpack-dev-server` for real time development.
Now, I am confused as to what to put in the `config -> output -> publicPath` in my config path:

```
var webpack = require("webpack");
var path = require("path");

var DIST_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname, "dist");
var SRC_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname, "src");

var config = {
    entry: SRC_DIR + "/index.js",
    output: {
        path: DIST_DIR,
        filename: "bundle.js",
        publicPath: "/app/"
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js?/,
                include: SRC_DIR,
                loader: "babel-loader",
                query: {
                    presets: ["react", "es2015", "stage-2"]
                }
            }
        ]
    }
};

module.exports = config;
```

Can somebody help? and what do you call this process?

Regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output is just for the bundling process (so you can deploy your code), webpack-dev-server serves the content through in memory files, you just need to set it up with this object :

```
devServer: {
    contentBase: publicPath,
    compress: true,
    hot: true,
    historyApiFallback: true,
    port: 8080
}
```

Checkout this link for more options : https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/